# How i can make a create() method using a instance of my model in adonis /node.js?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, lucid

I'm trying to make a insert using Lucid Models.

So, first i define my model in a `const`:

```
const ClasseLivroHistorico = use('App/Models/ClassBookHistoric')
```

This is my function that needs to create a new record:

```
async cadastraPrimeiroHistorico(classeId, bookUnitId, bookId){
    const primeiroClasseLivroHistorico = new ClasseLivroHistorico()
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.class_id = classeId;
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.book_unit_id = bookUnitId
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.book_id = bookId
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.status = false
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.created_at = new Date()
    primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.book_unit_sequence = 1
    await ClasseLivroHistorico.create(primeiroClasseLivroHistorico)

}
```

But i'm getting:

> insert into "xxx" ("$attributes", "$frozen", "$hidden",
>   "$originalAttributes", "$parent", "$persisted", "$relations",
>   "$sideLoaded", "$visible", "**setters**", "created_at", "updated_at")
>   values ($1, $2, DEFAULT, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, DEFAULT, $8, $9, $10)
>   returning "id" - column "$attributes" of relation
>   "xxx" does not exist"

I'm not using `.save()` because this return true/false and i need to return the created record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use new instance of `ClasseLivroHistorico` object you need to use [`save()`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_save) method. Like:

```js
const primeiroClasseLivroHistorico = new ClasseLivroHistorico()
...
await primeiroClasseLivroHistorico.save()

return primeiroClasseLivroHistorico
```

### or

If you want to use [`create()`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_create) method you have to give it the information in an array. Like:

```
let data = { class_id: classeId, ... }

const primeiroClasseLivroHistorico = await ClasseLivroHistorico.create(data)
```

*Don't hesitate if you need more information*